# How to push HTML list vales to a single JSON key as an array in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, json

I'm trying to get the text values of a HTML list and then push them to a single key value in a JSON object. I was hoping the JSON contents would look like `{"players": ["James","Emma","Vincent"]}`. My current attempt is below.

```js
// create array with empty player key
var infoArray = [{
    "players": ""
}];
// set the player key to a var
var mykey = 'players'; 

// for each player
$(".player").each(function () {
    infoArray[mykey].push({
      // add the player's name to the key
      $(this).text();
    });
});

//show the resulting json
$("#list").html(JSON.stringify(infoArray));
```

```css
pre {
    word-wrap:break-word;
    padding:10px;
    margin:10px;
    background:#eee;
    line-height: 1.7
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="player">James</li>
  <li class="player">Emma</li>
  <li class="player">Vincent</li>
</ul>
<h3>JSON result</h3>
<pre id="list"></pre>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Couple of things:

1) No need for `{` `}` in `push()` function

```
infoArray[mykey].push({ // <-- here
    $(this).text();
});
```

2) Don't initialize value of key `player` as empty string `""`, instead use empty array `[]`.

Also note that `infoArray` is a JSON array and not a JSON object.

---

```js
// create array with empty player key
var infoArray = [{
    "players": []
}];
// set the player key to a var
var mykey = 'players'; 

// for each player
$(".player").each(function () {
    var el = infoArray[0];
    el[mykey].push($(this).text());
});

//show the resulting json
$("#list").html(JSON.stringify(infoArray));
```

```css
pre {
    word-wrap:break-word;
    padding:10px;
    margin:10px;
    background:#eee;
    line-height: 1.7
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li class="player">James</li>
  <li class="player">Emma</li>
  <li class="player">Vincent</li>
</ul>
<h3>JSON result</h3>
<pre id="list"></pre>
```

Answer (score 0):

A little mistake here, your `infoArray` should be an object for exapmle:

```
let info = {
  "players": []
};
```

after this you can push there items like:

```
info.players.push('New item');
```

Answer (score 0):

remove `{}` :

```
$(".player").each(function () {
    infoArray[mykey].push(
      // add the player's name to the key
      $(this).text()
    );
});
```